# What's different between Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

When I do `cat /etc/redhat-release`, I got this.

```
#CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 5.5 (Tikanga)
```

It looks Red Hat Enterprise Linus is originated from CentOS. Anyway I want to use some linux personally  which is familiar to me. How the CentOS is different with Red Hat distribution? Can I use it similar manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have it backwards; CentOS is derived from RedHat Enterprise Linux. From the CentOS website:

> CentOS conforms fully with the upstream vendors redistribution policy
>   and aims to be 100% binary compatible. (CentOS mainly changes packages
>   to remove upstream vendor branding and artwork.)  CentOS is free.

It is basically the exact same OS, with different branding logos, is free to download, and support is done through a community of users rather than via a paid support subscription.